# Angular2 - Execute code after observable content update

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I need to create a routine that gets data from an HTTP service, and populates a `<form>`, then automatically calls `submit()` on the generated form:

```
<form  target="_top" #paymentForm action="{{payment?.Url}}" method="POST">
<input  *ngFor="let d of payment?.Data | keys" name="{{d}}" value= {{payment.Data[d]}}>
</form>
```

To populate this form I do a get request that returns the payment object, containing the URL and the form data to be posted:

```
this.globalsService.PlaceOrder(this.globalsService.ShoppingCart)
    .subscribe(res => {
                this.payment = res; 
                this.paymentForm.nativeElement.submit()
         });
```

Even though the code executes successfully and all data is eventually loaded into the form properly, at the moment the `submit()` action is executed the form is not yet populated, and therefore the redirect is wrong and all the values are mmissing.

I am looking for an elegant solution to this that does not involve setTimeout, redirecting to another route or using lifecycle hooks.

Comment: why you don't want to us lifecycle hooks? You can try model-driven form, and initialize it with default values (from globalsService). Using model-driven you can be sure that the form will be populated. On the other hand why u need a form, when you populate ALL of it controls from code. Wouldn't it be easier to just send a POST with http service?

Comment: Initializing a form with default values won't work. I need to submit the form with the values received from the web service.

Comment: You can use Form's methods : patchValue, setValue. And then make a POST request.